# GTMetrix Website Health, what is causing my website to load slowly sometimes but works fine other times?

Tags: html, css, web, waterfall, gtmetrix

my website appears to be loading normally (within 3 seconds) sometimes, then other times it takes about 25-30 seconds to load. I cannot understand why this happens. I've attached some screenshots, and the link to the GTMETRIX result is: https://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.docbot.org/m3KZ2qXV

Could someone help me out please?

Comment: This could be server load or a bad internet connection, id suggest using a CDN like cloudflare for better speeds

Comment: The internet connection isn't the issue, because when its slow, other websites load just fine

Comment: I meant the internet connection of the server